# Cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 after updating to AndroidX

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, androidx

When I updated all my android dependencies to androidx, I encountered this error when using DaggerAppCompatActivity "cannot access ActivityCompatApi23"

I tried searching for similar issues but fail to find one. As far as I understand, androidx is not giving the right support android library.

Full error log:

```
e: /Users/retina21/Desktop/android-projects/rhythmgame/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/kheldiente/midien/rhythmgame/BaseActivity.java:6: error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
public abstract class BaseActivity extends dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity {
                ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.AssertionError: annotation tree hasn't been attributed yet: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 13}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\"\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u000b\n\u0000\b&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\b\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0003J\u0012\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u00042\b\u0010\u0006\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0007H\u0014J\u0010\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\u00042\u0006\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\nH\u0016\u00a8\u0006\u000b"}, d2 = {"Lkheldiente/midien/rhythmgame/BaseActivity;", "Ldagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity;", "()V", "enableImmersiveMode", "", "onCreate", "savedInstanceState", "Landroid/os/Bundle;", "onWindowFocusChanged", "hasFocus", "", "app_debug"})
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:159)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:442)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1013)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1055)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1012)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:441)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: annotation tree hasn't been attributed yet: @kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 1, 13}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\"\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u000b\n\u0000\b&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002J\b\u0010\u0003\u001a\u00020\u0004H\u0003J\u0012\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u00042\b\u0010\u0006\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0007H\u0014J\u0010\u0010\b\u001a\u00020\u00042\u0006\u0010\t\u001a\u00020\nH\u0016\u00a8\u0006\u000b"}, d2 = {"Lkheldiente/midien/rhythmgame/BaseActivity;", "Ldagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity;", "()V", "enableImmersiveMode", "", "onCreate", "savedInstanceState", "Landroid/os/Bundle;", "onWindowFocusChanged", "hasFocus", "", "app_debug"})
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.checkNonNull(Assert.java:118)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.validateTypeAnnotation(Check.java:2745)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitAnnotation(Attr.java:4483)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAnnotation.accept(JCTree.java:2317)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitModifiers(TreeScanner.java:315)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCModifiers.accept(JCTree.java:2343)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$TypeAnnotationsValidator.visitClassDef(Attr.java:4565)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.validateTypeAnnotations(Attr.java:4472)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$2.run(TypeAnnotations.java:142)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:155)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:187)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:384)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:375)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:123)
    ... 29 more
```

EDIT:
Already tried cleaning and invalidating the caches and restart, still does not solve the issue

Comment: Some of the libraries you use depend on the old support library. Use Jetifier which will rewrite these old dependencies to AndroidX at compile time. In other words, [follow the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: I did update all of my libraries according to the documentation. android.useAndroidX=true  and android.enableJetifier=true are also included to gradle.properties. Only libraries i use that are not included there is dagger and rxjava. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, rxjava is unrelated, you can try updating dagger to latest version. There have been some issues related to AndroidX support in the past releases. [Check here.](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases) And as always, if everything else fails, run `gradlew clean && gradlew --stop`. This will remove any generated and intermediary files and kill the compiler deamon - no chance of any stale input. Then click the green hammer icon in Android Studio (Make Project) and try running the app.

Comment: I already tried cleaning and invalidating caches and restart. It still does not assemble when I build it. Yes, Ill check the dagger release logs. Thanks

Comment: (Good thing you tried clean build, but next time please mention right away what you have already tried, it helps focusing on the right/new things.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!